# jobDSL does not understand the type of parameters

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

While creating a Jenkins server, I use jobDSL to create jobs via pipeline.

Basically my created job ressembles this:

```
pipeline{
   parameters{
      string(name: "SAMPLE_PARAMETER")
   }
   stages{
      stage("Does not matter here"){
         //Does some work
      }
   }
}
```

When jobDSL tries to create a job out of this, I get an error saying that javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.BuildParametersContext.stringParam() can only work with (java.lang.string), (java.lang.string, java.lang.string) or (java.lang.string, java.lang.string, java.lang.string) and not with java.util.ArrayList

Can I force the type of "SAMPLE_PARAMETER", and if so how?

If this is not possible, how can I work around this?

Comment: When validating your code, the error I see thrown is `Missing required section "agent"`. Are you sure your code and/or error is accurate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Matt Schuchard in the comment he posted, I was missing the agent section, adding

> agent any

fixed my issue. I have no clue how it's related but it fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You are already passing type of variable. But if you still want to pass datatype,
you can simply use it like this.

```
string SAMPLE_PARAMETER1 = params.SAMPLE_PARAMETER
```

or

```
def SAMPLE_PARAMETER1 = params.SAMPLE_PARAMETER
SAMPLE_PARAMETER1 = SAMPLE_PARAMETER1.toString()
```

Comment: I don't get where I'm supposed to write those lines, I tried your 1st option in the parameters part, and I get an error telling me that there is no such property as params